# How to get value from dataSourceConfig autocomple material-ui reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const dataSource3 = [
  {textKey: 'Some Text', valueKey: 'someFirstValue'},
  {textKey: 'Some Text', valueKey: 'someSecondValue'},
];
const dataSourceConfig = {
  text: 'textKey',
  value: 'valueKey',
};

<AutoComplete id="city" ref="city" dataSource={datatest} dataSourceConfig={dataSourceConfig}/>
```

How to get the valueKey?

```
this.refs.brand.refs.searchTextField.input.value
```

If I use that code to retrieve the value, it just gets the textKey instead of valueKey